# Continuity of a function $f_{\alpha}(x,y)$

Tags: real-analysis

I have for $\alpha >0$ $$f_{\alpha}(x,y)=\frac{1+\sin(|x|^\alpha y)-\cos(x^2+y^4)}{x^2+y^4}$$ for $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$ and $0$ for $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

I want to study the continuity in $(0,0)$.

Can I use polar coordinates?

Comment: I maths, you never "have to" use a technique or a theorem to prove something.

Comment: First guess: Try $y=mx$. If the limit depends on m the limit to 0 does not exist.

Comment: I would start by considering the limit $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1 - \cos( t )} {t}$, and then you only have to consider $\frac{\sin( |x|^\alpha y )}{x^2+y^4}$.

Comment: $f_{\alpha}(x,mx)=\frac{|x|^{\alpha}mx}{x^2(1+m^4x^2)}$->0 for $\alpha>1?$